# Printing the value of loss that is minimized by an optimizer in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to print the value of loss that has been minimized by an optimizer. Here is an example:

```
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
MOMENTUM = 0.999

mean_squared_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(predictions, training_outputs)))
train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE, MOMENTUM).minimize(mean_squared_error)

# Load data
features = ...
labels = ...

# Launch TensorFlow session
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(initialize)

    print("Begin training...")
    session.run(train_step, feed_dict={training_inputs: features, training_outputs: labels})
    print("Finished training! The mean squared error is: _____")
```

Now that I have minimized `mean_squared_error`, how do I print its minimized value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to visualize a loss is to create a scalar summary of it:

```
mean_squared_error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(predictions, training_outputs)))
loss_summ = tf.scalar_summary("loss", mean_squared_error)
```

You then create a writer in the TensorFlow session, and add the summary `loss_summ` to the `sess.run()` call. You then get the value back in `mse_val` and can print it.

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("log", session.graph_def)
    session.run(initialize)

    print("Begin training...")
    _, mse_val, summ = session.run([train_step, mean_squared_error, loss_summ], feed_dict={training_inputs: features, training_outputs: labels})
    writer.add_summary(summ)
    print("Finished training! The mean squared error is: %f" % mse_val)
```

As a bonus, you can even visualize the evolution of the loss in TensorBoard, by running `tensorboard --logdir log` (read [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) for more details).

P.S: your code only runs 1 iteration of the training, you may want to add a loop.

Comment: I have upvoted your comment, and I will accept it once I try out your suggestions and find that they fulfill my needs. Thank you very much for your help! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: I ran your code, and I received a TypeError: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/Test/Prediction.py", line 77, in <module>
    print("Finished training! The mean squared error is: %f" % mean_squared_error_value)
TypeError: float argument required, not str`. I substituted `%f` with `%s`, but it ended up printing gibberish instead...

Comment: Sorry, you should add `mean_squared_error` in the `sess.run()` to get its value.
I edited my first answer with the changes, thank you !

Comment: Hi Olivier, thank you for your help so far. This is what I have written: `_, mean_squared_error_value, summary = session.run([train_step, mean_squared_error, loss_summary],
                                                        feed_dict={training_inputs: features, training_outputs: labels})`. Now I get the error message `TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected Summary got float32. for field Event.summary`.

Comment: Also change in the next line: `writer.add_summary(summary)`. You should pass the summary `summary` and not the MSE value to the Writer object.

Comment: Silly me -- I forgot to make changes to that part. Now it works :-) Thank you!